# Specified filed could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql

This error has aggravated me. I know that it is something small but cannot correct it.

```
SELECT
    tblPlayerStatistics.Player_ID_Number,
    SUM(tblPlayerStatistics.TwoPointerMade + tblPlayerStatistics.ThreePointerMade) AS points, 
    MatchID
FROM
    tblPlayerStatistics
    INNER JOIN tblGameResults ON tblPlayerStatistics.MatchID = tblGameResults.MatchID
GROUP BY
    tblPlayerStatistics.Player_ID_Number,
    tblPlayerStatistics.MatchID;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please elaborate your question like what error and table structure etc and use `code` block to display code correctly

Comment: @The Guy with The Hat the error message is "the specified field 'MatchID' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause in your SQL statement". The tables are player statistics and game results and i wnat to add the two pointers made and three pointers made in the player statistics table. Also add the game results table so that i can produce the highest number of points in one match. game results has the matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per what i understand from your question you have problem of same column present in more than one tables specify in from clause.
In this case you have to specify column with the table name as you have already done in your query.
OR else give table as alias name specify your column with alias name for that table.
Make correction in your current query.

```
SELECT
   tblPlayerStatistics.Player_ID_Number,
   SUM(tblPlayerStatistics.TwoPointerMade + tblPlayerStatistics.ThreePointerMade) AS points, 
   tblPlayerStatistics.MatchID
FROM
   tblPlayerStatistics
   INNER JOIN tblGameResults ON tblPlayerStatistics.MatchID = tblGameResults.MatchID
GROUP BY
   tblPlayerStatistics.Player_ID_Number,
   tblPlayerStatistics.MatchID;
```

Your `MatchID` is ambiguously defined, specify table name from which table you are using this column.

You may specify the alias name to table and used that alias name to access that table's column.
Using alias name :

```
SELECT
   ps.Player_ID_Number,
   SUM(ps.TwoPointerMade + ps.ThreePointerMade) AS points, 
   ps.MatchID
FROM
   tblPlayerStatistics ps
   INNER JOIN tblGameResults gr ON ps.MatchID = gr.MatchID
GROUP BY
   ps.Player_ID_Number,
   ps.MatchID;
```